# How to calculate percentage using MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to calculate percentage of with help of mongoDB aggregation,
My collection has following data.

| subject_id | gender | other_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Male | XYZ |
| 1 | Male | ABC |
| 1 | Male | LMN |
| 2 | Female | TBZ |
| 3 | Female | NDA |
| 4 | Unknown | UJY |

I want output something like this:

```
[{
  gender: 'Male',
  total: 1,
  percentage: 25.0
},{
  gender: 'Female',
  total: 2,
  percentage: 50.0
},{
  gender: 'Unknown',
  total: 1,
  percentage: 25.0
}]
```

I have tried various methods but none of them works, mainly unable to count total of Male, Female, Unknown summation(to calculate percentage). The trickiest part is there are only 4 members in above example but their `subject_id` may be repeated according to other_data

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How do you calculate percentage? 3/6 are Male and percentage is 25 while 1/6 is Unknown and also is 25. Can you please explain how to calculate the percentage?

Comment: @J.F. As I mentioned there are only 4 members, out of which 25%(1/4) Male, 50%(2/4) Female, 25%(1/4) Unknown.

Comment: Why there are only 4 members? Becuase there are 4 different `subject_id`?

Comment: @J.F Yes, `subject_id` is repeated but unique person wise. So 1 Person = 1 `subject_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First group by `subject_id` to get the different values (different persons).
- Then use `$facet` to create "two ways". One to use `$count` and get the total number of docs, and other to get the documents grouped by gender.
- Then with all desired values (grouped by gender and total docs) get the first element of the result from `nDocs` into `$facet` stage. `$facet` will generate an array and the value we want will be in the first position.
- Later use `$unwind` to get every `groupValue` with the `nDoc` value
- And last output the values you want using `$project`. To get the percentage you can `$divide` total/nDocs and `$multiply` by 100.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$subject_id",
      "gender": {
        "$first": "$gender"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "nDocs": [
        {
          "$count": "nDocs"
        },
        
      ],
      "groupValues": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$gender",
            "total": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "nDocs": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$nDocs",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$groupValues"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "gender": "$groupValues._id",
      "total": "$groupValues.total",
      "percentage": {
        "$multiply": [
          {
            "$divide": [
              "$groupValues.total",
              "$nDocs.nDocs"
            ]
          },
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HApTH480PWX)

Comment: This is the most perfect solution to my problem. Thanks a lot.